# In general is it better to use one or many useEffect hooks in a single component?

Tags: reactjs, performance, react-hooks, architecture, use-effect

I have some side effects to apply in my react component and want to know how to organize them:

- as a single useEffect
- or several useEffects

Which is better in terms of performance and architecture?

Comment: It probably matters depending on your use case, but I'm going to edit your question to make it clear this is covering general advice.

Answer (score 418, accepted):

The pattern that you need to follow depends on your use case.

**First:** You might have a situation where you need to add event listener during the initial mount and clean them up at unmount and another case where a particular listener needs to be cleaned up and re-added on a prop change.

In such a case, using two different `useEffect` is better to keep the relevant logic together as well as having performance benefits

```
useEffect(() => {
   // adding event listeners on mount here
   return () => {
       // cleaning up the listeners here
   }
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
   // adding listeners everytime props.x changes
   return () => {
       // removing the listener when props.x changes
   }
}, [props.x])
```

**Second:** You need to trigger an API call or some other side-effect when any of the state or props change from a defined set. In such a case a single `useEffect` with the relevant dependencies to monitor would be better

```
useEffect(() => {
    // side effect here on change of any of props.x or stateY
}, [props.x, stateY])
```

**Third:** You need separate side-effect for different sets of changes. In such a case, separate out relevant side-effects into different `useEffect`s

```
useEffect(() => {
   // some side-effect on change of props.x
}, [props.x])

useEffect(() => {
   // another side-effect on change of stateX or stateY 
}, [stateX, stateY])
```

Comment: what about a middle ground between **Second** and **Third** example above?: you have logic that runs when a subset of state/props change, but each has separate logic that needs to run in addition to some common code that needs to run? You wouldn't use `[]` (because it's still only a _subset_ of state/props you're awaiting changes for) but you'd also like to reuse code. Do you use separate `useEffects` and put the shared code in a function they each separately call?

Comment: As the answer below suggests, React team suggests separating hooks by concern, so you would split it into multiple `useEffect` calls.

Comment: Are they always triggered in the order of their definition?  i.e.  effect1 is always called first, then effect2?

Comment: @computrius [Yes](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-use-multiple-effects-to-separate-concerns), `React will apply every effect used by the component, in the order they were specified.`

Comment: What if I have multiple "componentDidMount" effects (empty array []) but they do very different things? should I put them in a single useEffect or multiple?

Answer (score 93):

You should use multiple effects to [separate concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) as [suggested by reactjs.org](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-use-multiple-effects-to-separate-concerns).

Comment: I know, but it would improve your answer if you explained why separation of concern, and whether that's an architectural or performance concept.

Answer (score 24):

It's perfectly [fine](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-use-multiple-effects-to-separate-concerns) to have have multiple useEffect.

Here's how one of my setups looks like:

```
/*
 * Backend tags list have changed add the changes if needed
 */
useEffect(() => {
    setTagsList(setTagsAdded);
}, [setTagsAdded]);

/*
 * Backend files have changed add the changes if needed
 */
useEffect(() => {
    for (let i = 0; i < changedFilesMeta.length; i += 1) {
        // Is the list item value changed
        if (changedFilesMeta[i].id === currentEditableFile.id) {
            unstable_batchedUpdates(() => {
                setTags(changedFilesMeta[i].tags ? changedFilesMeta[i].tags : []);
            });
        }
    }
}, [changedFilesMeta]);

/*
 * Reset when user select new files using the filepicker
 */
useEffect(() => {
    if (setNewFiles.length > 0) {
        unstable_batchedUpdates(() => {
            setCurrentFile(null);
            setDescription('');
            setTitle('');
            setTags([]);
        });
    }
}, [setNewFiles]);

/*
 * User selecet to edit a file, change to that file
 */
useEffect(() => {
    // When user select a file to edit it
    if (currentEditableFile && currentEditableFile !== theCurrentFile) {
        setCurrentFile(currentEditableFile);
        unstable_batchedUpdates(() => {
            setDescription(currentEditableFile.description);
            setTitle(currentEditableFile.title);
            setTags(currentEditableFile.tags);
        });
    }
}, [currentEditableFile]);
```

Comment: could you add some more of your code, to make it clear what bit of state `setTags` is updating? Is `setTagsAdded` a function or object? Also how have you made sure 'performance and architecture' are better this way round vs. one big useEffect?

Comment: I don't think including this code, especially out of context, is helpful or relevant to the question.

Comment: @Bricky regardless, stripping out all the code AND adding in a quote changes the answer too much to justify it

Comment: The quote is the relevant section *from the link*. Simply including a link is a low-effort answer.