# useEffect to only update a specific key updates

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, use-effect

I have a scenario where our application has multiple functions that sit within `componentDidUpdate`. In each of the functions they check to see if their specific data is updated. For example:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
 this.handleFoo(prevProps)
 this.handleMoreFoo(prevProps)
}

handleFoo(prevProps){
  if(this.props.foo != prevProps.foo){
    //Do Something
 }
}

handleMoreFoo(prevProps){
  if(this.props.moreFoo != prevProps.moreFoo){
    //Do Something
 }
}
```

I have been looking at the `useEffect` hook and was wondering if I could chop out that initial check in each of these functions and utilize the `[]` in `useEffect` and only call one of these functions if their specific key is updated like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
   if(fooKey){ handleFoo() }
   if(moreFoo) { handleMoreFoo() }
 }, [fooKey, moreFooKey])
```

Is this possible? Is this advisable?

Comment: Call `useEffect()` for each `handleX()` you had prior. The great thing about hooks is that they can function independently of each other and _don't_ need to share a common entry point like the lifecycle methods in the class components.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [Should I use one or many useEffect in component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54002792/should-i-use-one-or-many-useeffect-in-component/54004148#54004148)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you'd accomplish what you had before, using hooks in a functional component.

I'd define a custom hook to mimic `componentDidUpdate()`, based on the answer to [Make React useEffect hook not run on initial render](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53254028/1541563):

```
function useUpdate (effect, deps) {
  const firstUpdate = useRef(true);
  const update = useCallback(() => {
    if (firstUpdate.current) {
      firstUpdate.current = false;
    } else {
      return effect();
    }
  }, [firstUpdate, effect]);

  useLayoutEffect(update, deps);
}

...

useUpdate(handleFoo, [fooKey]);
useUpdate(handleMoreFoo, [moreFooKey]);
```

`useLayoutEffect()` ensures that the `handleX()` callbacks are invoked at the same phase of each render as the analogous `componentDidMount()` and `componentDidUpdate()` lifecycle methods. If you don't care about the exact phase in which they're invoked, you can replace `useLayoutEffect()` with `useEffect()`.

The rest of the custom hook ensures that it skips calling the `handleX()` callbacks after the initial render. If your `handleX()` callbacks *can* be called after the initial render, then you can just call `useEffect()` directly in your functional component instead of this `useUpdate()` custom hook.

Comment: hey is there a way to make sure that the hooks fire in the same order this way? I see now that that is a hard rule of hooks.

Comment: @GrantHerman fire in the same order? They'll fire in the order the hooks are instantiated. Does that answer your question?