# Await not working in useEffect with redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I am trying to fetch some data from the API and setting the data in my redux store. However, when I try to do some operation with the data from the redux store that variable is empty. I have used await but it seems it does not work. However, after useEffect the redux store(api data) data is visible and can do operations on it. Any help is appreciated. **Please note I need to access the redux store field not just get the returned data from the function**. Accessing the redux store field is important. Here is my code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function loadData() {
      const startingDateYear = moment();
      const eventDates = generateDatesForYear(startingDateYear.year().toString());
      await dispatch(fetchData('0009', eventDates[0], eventDates[1]));
    }
    loadData();
    console.log(event.myDataArray) // event is a reducer and myDataArray is the field. It can be accessed outside the function with data incorporated but within useEffect I am not able to use the freshly fetched data.
    return {};
  }, []);


 export const fetchData = (p1, p2, p3) => {
  return async dispatch => {
    const path = `dataFromAPIURL`;
    try {
      dispatch({
        type: FETCH_STARTED,
      });

      const myDataArray = await RestService.get(path);
      dispatch({
        type: FETCH_FINISHED,
      });

      dispatch({
        type: UPDATE_REDUCER_STATE,
        payload: myDataArray,
      });

      return myDataArray;
    } catch (error) {
      // TODO: error handling
      dispatch({ type: FETCH_ERROR, payload: error });
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: You defined loadData as an async function, but you are not calling it with await

Comment: Even If I use await there and make useEffect Async it still does not work since I need to access the redux store field. And yes making useEffect async does not seem the most elegant solution at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a second useEffect with dependency `event.myDataArray`

```js
useEffect(() => {
  async function loadData() {
    const startingDateYear = moment();
    const eventDates = generateDatesForYear(startingDateYear.year().toString());
    await dispatch(fetchData("0009", eventDates[0], eventDates[1]));
  }
  loadData();
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(event.myDataArray);
}, [event.myDataArray]);
```

Comment: It does work but why do I need a second useEffect? Shouldnt await be sufficient since I just need to wait for my dispatches to finish ?

Comment: My useEffect is more like component did mount and adding a second effect would make things more complicated since I think it is not needed.

Comment: It would be super nice If we could do it with one useEffect as previously withCompnent Did Mount?

Comment: @HassanAbbas you can't directly access it in the first useEffect,  this is the nature of useEffect.

Comment: @HassanAbbas you can learn more about this in this [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-use-multiple-effects-to-separate-concerns)

Comment: Also  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54002792/should-i-use-one-or-many-useeffect-in-component is helpful.